# ExcelReader, first row getting skipped

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I am developing a small plugin for an ERP System, that is reading from Excel file, and inserting into the database (SQL). For som reason with this current sheet, the first row is getting skipped. I tried working around the issue, and when a SQL error is thrown, when i force the program to insert something that is not valid, the row appear in the SQL database.

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong, because i feel like i have tried everything.

**Customer Class**

```
class Customer
{

    public int ActNo {get;set;}
    public int CustNo { get; set; }
    public string DelPri { get; set; }
    public int CustPrg3 = 22;
    public string Nm { get; set; }
    public int Gr6 = 5;
    public int CreDt { get; set; }
    public string CreUsr { get; set; }


    public Customer(int ActNo,int CustNo, string DelPri, string Nm, int CreDt){
    this.ActNo = ActNo;
    this.CustNo = CustNo;
    this.DelPri = DelPri;
    this.CustPrg3 = 22;
    this.Nm = Nm;
    this.Gr6 = 5;
    this.CreUsr = "Excel";
    this.CreDt = CreDt;
}

}
```

**The Reader**

```
public class ExcelData
{
    string _path;

    public ExcelData(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public IExcelDataReader getExcelReader()
    {
        // ExcelDataReader works with the binary Excel file, so it needs a FileStream
        // to get started. This is how we avoid dependencies on ACE or Interop:
        FileStream stream = File.Open(_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        // We return the interface, so that
        IExcelDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            if (_path.EndsWith(".xls"))
            {
                reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
            }
            if (_path.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
            {
                reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
            }
            return reader;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> getWorksheetNames()
    {
        var reader = this.getExcelReader();
        var workbook = reader.AsDataSet();
        var sheets = from DataTable sheet in workbook.Tables select sheet.TableName;
        return sheets;
    }



    public IEnumerable<DataRow> GetSecondSheetData(bool firstRowIsColumnNames = true)
    {
        var reader = this.getExcelReader();
        reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = firstRowIsColumnNames;
        return reader.AsDataSet().Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
    }



}
```

**Using the Reader, and adding to customer Array**

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            int maxActNo = 0;
            int maxCustNo = 0;

            var excelData = new ExcelData(path);
            var albums = excelData.GetSecondSheetData();
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

            Customer testCust = new Customer(1, 1, "Test", "Test", Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")));
            customers.Add(testCust);




            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            rdr.Read();
            maxActNo = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["HighestActNo"]);
            maxCustNo = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["HighestCustNo"]);
            rdr.Close();

            foreach (var row in albums)
            {
                if (row.ItemArray.Length == 8
                                              && row.ItemArray[0].ToString() != "Dato"
                                              //&& row.ItemArray[0].ToString().Contains(convertedDate)
                                              && row.ItemArray[1].ToString() != "Varenummer"
                                              && row.ItemArray[2].ToString() != "Varenavn"
                                              && row.ItemArray[3].ToString() != "Kundekonto"
                                              && row.ItemArray[4].ToString() != "Navn"
                                              && row.ItemArray[5].ToString() != "Antall"
                                              && row.ItemArray[6].ToString() != "Antall"
                                              && row.ItemArray[7].ToString() != "Enhet"
                                              //&& row.ItemArray[0].ToString() != ""
                                              //&& row.ItemArray[1].ToString() != ""
                                              //&& row.ItemArray[2].ToString() != ""
                                              //&& row.ItemArray[3].ToString() != ""
                                              //&& row.ItemArray[4].ToString() != ""
                                              //&& row.ItemArray[5].ToString() != ""
                                              //&& row.ItemArray[6].ToString() != ""
                                              //&& row.ItemArray[7].ToString() != ""
                    )                                                                        
                {

                    Customer cust = new Customer(
                    maxActNo,
                    maxCustNo,
                    row[3].ToString(),
                    row[4].ToString(), 
                    Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")));

                    if (customers[customers.Count() - 1].DelPri != row[3].ToString())
                    {
                        customers.Add(cust);

                        maxActNo++;
                        maxCustNo++;

                    }


                }
            }
            customers.RemoveAt(0);
            ImportController controller = new ImportController();
            controller.insertCustomerIfNotExist(customers);
            button2.Enabled = false;

        }

    }
```

I have chosen not to show the SQL, since i know that the probleb is not in the QUERY, it is somewhere in my if statements that the row is getting sorted, out yet i have tried for hours and figured i needed a hint.

Appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone seeing this i figured out why my code was not running like i Expected.
There are no errors in the code above, i was blind to my insert loop which started from index 1, instead of index 0.

Closing this question, but thanks to anyone who read, or tried to answer.

```
for (int i = 1; i < customers.Count; i++)
```

Needed to be

```
for (int i = 0; i < customers.Count; i++)
```

in the insert function.